# How to increase and make package a wide layout?

Tags: geometry

I have tried to increase the page layout using the geometry package but I can simply seem to move the text to the left but the total width of the page stays the same

```
\usepackage[top=0.2in, bottom=0.2in, left=0.9in, right=7.5in]{geometry}
```

Using class file with the following:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{res}[2000/05/19 v1.4b Resume class]

%\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
%\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}

\PassOptionsToClass{11pt,12pt}{article}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
```

Comment: 7.5in is an unusually wide right margin. Are you sure about this?

Comment: There is no point in passing both `11pt` and `12pt` to `article`. Only one font size can be applied.

Comment: ahh ok, I just want to make sure that the article is a wide layout, I am trying to do so through geometry package

Comment: I'll fix the font size to only one of them

Comment: @cft so is there a way that I can increase the width?

Comment: Yes. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371518/how-to-increase-and-make-package-a-wide-layout?noredirect=1#comment917627_371518

Comment: @cfr err.. how? could you please give an example..

Comment: 7.5in is an unusually wide margin. Are you sure about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59263/discussion-between-cfr-and-tsar2512).